# How to reset default shell for root from user space

Tags: command-line, unix

I've switched my bash to zsh in root using 
`chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh root`

After when I change back to bash, I type the wrong path:
`chsh -s /usr/bin/bash root`

Now I cannot enter root and I get this prompt, how can I reset it?

```
user@ip:~$ sudo su
Cannot execute /usr/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message indicates, you have set the wrong path for `bash`. `bash` is located at `/bin/bash`, not `/usr/bin/bash`.

On some Linux distros, `/bin/bash` may be a symlink to `/usr/bin/bash`, but this is NOT what macOS does. **There's no `/usr/bin/bash` on macOS**, just `/bin/bash`.

Use the following command to set shell as Bash for `root` correctly.

```sh
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash root
```

The default shell for `root` user is `/bin/sh`, if you wanna reset it,

```sh
sudo chsh -s /bin/sh root
```

Comment: macOS is not a (Linux) distro :-)

Comment: @nohillside I know that, I was just pointing out the symlink behaviors are different, which may be the reason why the questioner set a wrong path.

Comment: Can you please explain what "symlink behaviors" means? `sh` is not symlink to `bash` nor is `/bin` a symlink to `/usr/bin` on a OS X system.

Comment: @fd0 Thanks. Just emphasized it in the 2nd paragraph. `bin/bash` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/bash` on Linux, but not on macOS. There's no `/usr/bin/bash` on macOS, just `/bin/bash`.

Comment: There are no symlinks involved here, the OP just used the wrong path when setting the default shell for `root`. The problem (and the solution) would be the same if the OP would have set the default shell to `/usr/bin/false` for instance.

Comment: Simba, You said, "`bin/bash` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/bash` on Linux" and that is not a true statement for all Linux distros! As an example with Linux Mint 19 in a terminal, `ls -ld /bin` returns `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 5 2019 /bin` and  `which bash` returns `/bin/bash` and `ls -l /bin/bash` returns `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1113504 Apr 4 2018 /bin/bash`, so no symlinks and it's in `/bin` not `/usr/bin` as you've so stated. Frankly, as macOS is not Linux, it's best to leave Linux out of it as it's really not relevant to macOS what is or isn't in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following->

```
sudo -s
```

Enter your admin password. The prompt should now end in `#`.
Enter->

```
chsh -s /bin/sh root
```

and exit the "root" shell and test.

Comment: Running `sudo chsh -s /bin/sh root` should work as well.